# Why must loop variables be signed in a parallel for?

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp, signed

I'm just learning OpenMP from online tutorials and resources. I want to square a matrix (multiply it with itself) using a `parallel for` loop. In [IBM compiler documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Fcompiler%2Fref%2Fruompplf.htm), I found the requirement that "the iteration variable must be a `signed` integer." Is this also true in the GCC implementation? Is it specified in the OpenMP standard? If so, is there a reason for this requirement?

(It doesn't matter much as the expected dimensions are far smaller than `INT_MAX`, but it does cost me some casts.)

Comment: This question was marked as a dupe of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820621), but there's a difference, which is that I was specifically interested in GCC's OpenMP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to OpenMP 3.0 specification: http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/spec30.pdf, for variable may be of a signed or unsigned integer type, see 2.5.1 Loop Construct. The question is whether given OpenMP implementation matches this latest specification.

Comment: Accepted because the restriction has been lifted in 3.0, so there probably wasn't a good reason for it in the first place.

Answer (score 10):

Quoting from [Why aren't unsigned OpenMP index variables allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820621) :

> According to the [OpenMP 2.0 C/C++
>   API](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/cspec20.pdf) specification (pdf), section
>   2.4.1, that's one of the restrictions of the for loop. No reason is given
>   for it, but I suspect it's just to
>   simplify the assumptions that the code
>   and compiler have to make, since
>   there's special code to ensure that
>   the range doesn't overflow the maximum
>   value of the type.
>
> OpenMP 3.0 apparently allows for
>   unsigned types too, but I haven't seen
>   it in action yet.

In short, it's part of the standard and the next version will allow unsigned integers.

Comment: I'm stuck with GCC 4.3, which implements OpenMP 2.5. I'll cast my `size_t` to `int` for now.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a possible reason behind that. The [same article](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v101v121/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp101.linux.doc/compiler_ref/prag_omp_for.html) says that

- `b, ub, incr` are loop invariant signed integer expressions and
- `exit_cond` takes form: `iv <= ub` or `iv <  ub` or `iv >= ub` or `iv >  ub` (where `iv` is the iteration variable you ask about)

since the `exit_cond` condition involves a comparison and the comparison is done against a signed `ub` variable the loop variable `iv` has to be signed to avoid possible problems with signed/unsigned comparison.

Comment: +1 for the reason. It's always good to know **why** things are the way they are.

Comment: Which begs the question why the other expressions must be `signed`.

Comment: Hm, that is no real reason. If the reason would be, you have to have the bounds and the counter of the same type, including signedness. That one I would buy.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your first question about `gcc`. No, it seems that `gcc` easily accepts `unsigned` or `size_t` loop variables in something like

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  /* do it */
}
```

at least mine (gcc v 4.4 on a 64bit ubuntu) doesn't complain *and* does the right thing.